# How do I print to a USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, printing

I don't own a printer. I want to print on-line documents such as coupons and airline tickets to a USB drive which I will then take to the Staples store for printing. I want to keep the bar codes intact.

How can I print to the pen drive?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: you want a "print-to-file" option, or "export-as-PDF", which will ask you where to save the file, and you'll save it to the flash drive.

Comment: @quack quixote: Does Staples support opening PDF files for printing?  just wondering?

Comment: @studiohack23: they didn't when i worked there, but that was more than a decade ago.  (long before they had computers and you could print stuff out.)  last time i went in to print something was *nearly* a decade ago, and your file had to be on floppy (not CD, and this was pre-flash-drive), but i think they had PDF viewers on the kiosks.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Windows, you could install **CutePDF (free)**, which allows you to save any printable document to a PDF. You could save the PDF files to your thumbdrive, then transport them to Staples.

[Link to CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)

If you're using a Mac, in the standard print dialog you can select PDF -> Save to PDF...

Comment: +1 cause that's exactly what i was about to suggest ;p

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need to install CutePDF - select a Postscript printer and Print to File. (this will give you a postscript file).

To create a "print to Postscript" virtual printer in Windows XP, follow these steps:

1. Start the Add Printer Wizard (Start -> Printers & Faxes -> Add Printer).
2. Select *"Local printer"*, and uncheck the *"Automatically detect and install"* checkbox.
3. Select *"Use the following port"*. In the dropdown, select *"FILE: (Print to File)"*.
4. This is where you choose a driver; you need a Postscript driver for this.  Good ones are the *"Apple Color LW 12/660 PS"*, *"Apple LaserWriter 12/640 PS"*, and *"Apple LaserWriter 16/600 PS"*.  If you want to print in color, use the *"Apple Color LW 12/660 PS"*.  Drivers for all of these are provided by Microsoft, so there's no need for additional downloads.
5. Set the name for the printer or leave the default.  Set it as the default printer if you want.
6. Share and print a test file as desired, and finish the wizard.

When complete, you'll have a new "printer" available to your applications.  When printing to this virtual printer, a popup dialog will ask where to save the output file.  It will be a Postscript file, but you may need to add the `.ps` file extension by hand.  There are free tools that will convert Postscript to PDF if you prefer (such as *ps2pdf* from the GNU Ghostview utility).

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, just hit `Command+P` (or `File` -> `Print`), click the `PDF` button at the bottom-left of the dialogue and choose `Save as PDF...`

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you DoPDF. It exactly do what you want.

[More Info here](http://www.dopdf.com/)